# Why does APK with the same size take different times to install?

Tags: android, performance, apk

I'm developing an app store and in that store there are two apps:

- First app: 47mb
- Second app: 34mb

When installing these apps on my device, I have the following result:

- First app: 30 seconds
- Second app: 1 minute

*This installation time only, disregarding the download time.*

I would like to understand the possible causes that make the first app install much faster than the second, even though it is bigger.

can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different compression settings for the files contained in the APK?

Comment: I'm not about to vote this as *off-topic* (I've been out of the Android-dev game too long), but this might be too broad of a question. There can be many factors such as what else the device is doing at the time, compression level of the APK, what else the installation does aside from simply copying files, battery optimization, security scans, etc. that can factor in here.

Comment: I would agree with @BendertheGreatest. This is a very broad question. IT could also mean that you are installing both apps at the same time? meaning decompressing them at the same time?
Can you provide more context and data? Did you try measuring different stages of the installation process? how do you trigger the installation of the APKs? etc

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks for the answer, I will ask the app owners what compression settings they use

Comment: Hi @BendertheGreatest

The test performed was with identical devices and also on the same device.

We created an application just to perform the installation, to ensure that it would not have any processes running in parallel, so I suspect that the problem may be in the application.

Comment: Hi @Jorge, The tests were always installing one app at a time.

To trigger the installation we are using the Google library.